# Add customer message upon order change to processing based on conditions in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, custom-taxonomy

This code works, it adds a note to the order if the customer buys a product which is in a conditional category as well as other products outside of that category and the order is moved to processing. The message is that the customer will receive 2 packages since they ship from different locations. However, I want it to add the message as a customer message rather than a note, but I can't get it to work.

I tried with

```
    $order->set_customer_note($customer_note);
    $order->save();
```

but it doesn't work.

My code attempt:

```
    function add_custom_note_to_order($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Initialize categories array
    $categories = array();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $terms = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
        
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            $categories[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }

    // Categories to check
    $check_categories = array('accessories-1', 'shirtsblue', 'shirtsred', 'shirtsgreen');

    // Check if order contains products from the cat above
    // and also from another category
    if(array_intersect($check_categories, $categories) && sizeof(array_diff($categories, $check_categories)) > 0) {
        $order_note = 'Your order will be shipped in 2 parcels';
        $order->add_order_note($order_note);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'add_custom_note_to_order');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`WC_Order` `add_order_note()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php#L1876-L1942), there is `$is_customer_note` 2nd optional argument *(boolean)*, that you need to set it to `true`, like:

```
$order_note = 'Your order will be shipped in 2 parcels';

$order->add_order_note($order_note, true);
```

Now it should work.